# Taxonomy of wordpress page - archives.php

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

The question is quite simple but it got me stacked.

If my blog is located on "**domain.com**" then which url will display source of "archives.php" page?

1. category source is displayed by category.php
2. tag source is displayed by archive.php
3. calendar data e.g. 2016/01/11/ is still displayed by archive.php
4. archives.php? What does it display?

**What url causes wordpress to use archives.php?**

Comment: See https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#examples

Comment: Thanks Milap, but I misspelled my question. I want to know about "arhives.php". Any idea?

Comment: checkout my detailed answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you access http://example.com/blog/category/your-cat/, it will look for archives.php in your activated theme.

If your blog is at http://example.com/blog/ and a visitor clicks on a link to a category page such as http://example.com/blog/category/your-cat/, WordPress looks for a template file in the current theme’s directory that matches the category’s ID to generate the correct page. More specifically, WordPress follows this procedure:

1. Looks for a template file in the current theme’s directory that matches the category’s slug. If the category slug is “unicorns,” then WordPress looks for a template file named category-unicorns.php.
2. If category-unicorns.php is missing and the category’s ID is 4, WordPress looks for a template file named category-4.php.
3. If category-4.php is missing, WordPress will look for a generic category template file, category.php.
4. If category.php does not exist, WordPress will look for a generic archive template, archive.php.
5. If archive.php is also missing, WordPress will fall back to the main theme template file, index.php.

Source : https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#examples

Comment: You have some of your logic wrong here. When you visit a category page, WordPress will not look for `archive.php`. Also, WordPress does not look for a template according to ID. What does happen is, WordPress uses the query object and create 3 template names in `get_category_template()`, `category-{slug}`, `category-{ID}.php` and `category.php` and store them in an array which gets passed to `get_query_template()` which goes through every generated template name. The first template that exist is loaded in the order I have in which they are created. If none are found, the next condition in .....

Comment: template loader that valuates true is `is_archive()` and then `get_archive_template()` is used which will test to see if `archive.php` exist and loads it if available. If this fails, the whole condition defaults to use `get_index_template()` which simply loads 'index.php`

Comment: You should go and check out how templates are loaded according to the [template loader](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4/src/wp-includes/template-loader.php#L58).

Answer (score 0):

`archive.php`, if available, is a fall back template for all types of archives if no higher ranking template exists in the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) to display the current archive on. `archive.php` comes in just before `index.php` (*which is the last resort and a must-have template*). If no specific template is available for a given archive page, and `archive.php` is not available, `index.php` will ultimately be used to render the page on.

The following is accepted as archives and all archives in the list will use `archive.php` if there is no specific template available higher up in their template hierarchy: (*Make sure you check out the hierarchy for each archive and check where `archive.php` and `index.php` slots in*)

- Category pages
- Taxonomy pages
- Tag pages
- Date and time pages
- Custom post type archive pages
- Author pages

To answer your question, any URL which is recognised as an archive page can load `archive.php` if:

- it is available
- and most importantly, no specific template in the template hierarchy is available for that specific archive being viewed

### EDIT

You should go and check out how the [template loader](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4/src/wp-includes/template-loader.php#L58) is used to load templates for different requests. This will help you understand the template hierarchy

Answer (score -1):

it is actually display the content of `index.php` by default untill you are not using any custom page selected in

> wp-admin **Settings** > `General`

For category page. Read about [What Template File is Used?](https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates)

For Tag source [What Template File is Used?](https://codex.wordpress.org/Tag_Templates)

Comment: you may need to look over the template hierarchy 
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/